# How to separate many telephone numbers in one MySQL row to display to web page

Tags: mysql-5.5, php

My table is like this,

[image]

I need an output like this,

[image]

How can I get this using PHP & MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest - and properly fastest - would be to split it in the code instead of SQL, when it's structured/stored like that.

Comment: thanks Allan S. Hansen. But I don't want to change my table structure. I need displaying telephone numbers separately in my web page

Comment: In your php code use explode function to split the numbers on the ',' character. See example #3 php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php